# How to count the number of blue items in video in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

This is an example of what I will be seeing, I am trying to count the number of items that are blue in the video. In this example it would be 2, my shirt and the phone. How would I go about doing this?
[image]

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    width = int(cap.get(3))
    height = int(cap.get(4))

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([90, 50, 50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame', result)
    cv2.imshow('mask', mask)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @PCM Nothing is wrong with the current code, it allows me to see only the blue pixels on the screen. I am trying to add to that code to allow me to count the number of blue items in the video.